# Does refactoring XML-serializable public fields as auto properties break deserialization of old instances?

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, xml-serialization

I have a class which has a number of public fields that are marked with XML serializable attributes:

```
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ExampleField = string.Empty;
```

I intend to refactor these fields (and only these fields) as auto-properties:

```
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string ExampleField { get; set; }
```

Will there be any issue with deserializing instances that were created using the previous version of the class?

Comment: AFAIK, it shouldn't, but I'm not expert enough to put this as answer ;)

Comment: If you already have the serializer code, couldn't you just send it two different classes and compare the output yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to work just fine...

(`XmlSerializer` is *my* wrapper to the .Net Xml Serialization classes.)

```
[Test]
public void XmlOutTest()
{
    var field = new Field { ExampleField = "TEXT" };
    var property = new Property() { ExampleField = "TEXT" };

    var fieldXml = XmlSerializer<Field>.Serialize(field);
    var propertyXml = XmlSerializer<Property>.Serialize(property);

    System.Console.WriteLine(fieldXml);
    System.Console.WriteLine(propertyXml);

    Assert.IsNotNull(XmlSerializer<Field>.Deserialize(propertyXml));
    Assert.IsNotNull(XmlSerializer<Property>.Deserialize(fieldXml));
}

public class Field
{
    public string ExampleField = string.Empty;
}

// changing root so I can use each other's xml when deserializing
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("Field")]
public class Property
{
    public string ExampleField { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Field>
  <ExampleField>TEXT</ExampleField>
</Field>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Field>
  <ExampleField>TEXT</ExampleField>
</Field>
```